# how we add row /Remove row effect in datagrid

Tags: apache-flex

how we add effect in datagrid when we add or remove any row.

Thanks
Atul yadav

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported as of Flex 4.6.

On the other hand, the effect is supported on MX List and MX TileList controls, if you can use them instead of DataGrid. In these controls, you can specify an effect with 'itemsChangeEffect', for example the DefaultListEffect that fades and collapses a row it when it is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use properties 'addedEffect' and 'removedEffect' for DataGrid.
Define effect then use it. Smth like this:

```
<mx:EffectName id='effectId' here effect properties/>
<mx:DataGrid addedEffect='effectId'/>
```

Comment: This will play the effect when the entire DataGrid is added/removed. It will not play the effect when individual rows are added/removed.